# How do I make a dialog pop up in angular without redirecting to another component/page?

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

So far I already have a working dialog from angular/material(https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) and it works well, but what I am trying to do is prevent the client from going to another page when they click on the link or search in the URL '/messages'. For example, if I am on the home page "/home" and if the client searches in URL "/messages" while on the home page, I want the dialog to pop up but stay on the home page. The same thing for the link, if I am on the "/about" page and click a link that navigates to the "/messages" page, I want to stay on the "/about" page while the dialog is outputted to the browser.

Comment: open `mat-dialog` using button click event. so that when dialog if press Yes then navigate to new page or if Press No then stay on the same page its simple use-case

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thx for the fast response, but can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog take look at this stackblitz link here when you click

Comment: I don't quite understand. I have tried it with a (click) event, but that only worked for the link and that didn't change the URL to "/messages". At the moment I have changed it to router link now, but that's the issue I stated.

Comment: I am aware of that,  but that's not what I'm talking about. Specifically, my dialog will actually be a messaging component. Similar to how Quora has theirs on their web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete working example you can find here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-og1ojj?file=app%2Fhn.resolver.ts)

You can use guard service for protecting routing path. create route guard and put code like this..

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

   if (this.guardSerive.open()) {
     return true;
   }else{
     this._router.navigate(['/Home']);
   }
}
```

In your service you have one method call in guard service like this...

```
open(){
   let result = window.confirm('Are you sure want to move?')
   return result;
}
```

Your Routing path in app-routing.module.ts is...

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
     {path:'Home', component: ExampleComponent},
     {path: 'generate', component:GenerateComponent,
     canActivate: [HnResolver]},
     {path:'', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ])
```

Comment: Thanks this is almost exactly what I am looking for, but at the moment I'm switching things up to have it exactly how I need it. But the thing is that I don't want it to ask for permission. When the user searches in the URL "/messages", I just want the dialog to pop up no matter what page they're on and expect it to remain on that same page from when they accessed their messages when they close the dialog.

Comment: I have done that, but now I am having difficulties trying to stay on the same page. For the if-else statement, I decided to take the else off and another I tried to actually go back to the last page using location, but the dialog immediately takes off...Instead of navigating to another route, I want to stay put.

Comment: share your forked stackblitz link here

Comment: I didn't change much but the dialog only. My focus here is not about clicking on any links. I am only focusing on when the client searches in the url. I found it strange that I couldn't go the "generate" route when I inputted in the url. We start off in the home page, Now when I search "generate" in the url, I want that dialog to pop up while I am still in the "Home" route. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-kjdp51

Comment: This is the one, sorry, not the one above. I thought the changes saved https://angular-mat-dialog-kjdp51.stackblitz.io/Home So when you click 'pick one' and click on the 'create' it takes you to the 'generate' route and opens the dialog. I want that same dialog to fire when the client searches in the url 'generate' but all while staying on the 'Home' route. I'm really sorry I'm carrying it this far. Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: I am sorry, not used to stackblitz, but I fixed it. Hopefully, this one won't break https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-omnin4

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-og1ojj?file=app%2Fhn.resolver.ts checkk out this link . I have updated code here of what you want to do.

Comment: hey, this is exactly what I asked for in the comment above.......but I as I stated in the first comment I don't want to limit it only to the home page. I said that I want them to remain on whatever page they are in. Does not matter if they're on the "about " page or "blog" page, when they access the messages in the url, it opens the dialog, then when they close, to remain on whatever page they were. I was just using the "home" page as an example. Sorry if I didn't make this clear. But after that, then It should all be complete.

Comment: All I did was replace the navigators with "this.location.back()" is this a "right" way and efficient way of doing it? It seems to work. Big thank you, bro! :)

Answer (score 0):

The type of behaviour you want can be achieved using `Route guard`. Based on your response from Route guard you can show the pop up containing relevant message.

**Note:** adding working code...